# Apache Druid Datasources creation

Tags: druid

I have a Druid platform deployed without a router (and therefore no UI) on Kubernetes. I noticed that some datasources have disappeared (most probably erased manually). Is there a way to re-created them manually without re-deploying the full platform (for example, by restarting the ingestion server, through an API call, other)?
Thanks - Christian

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the data was deleted and whether the segment files are still being pointed to by the Metadata Database.

Your best starting point is the full Druid API documentation.

For example, they may be in Deep Storage and still in Metadata DB but just marked as "unused", in which case you can use an API:

`https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/api-reference.html#post-1`

Or they could be "used" in the MDDB but just not being loaded, in which case check the Load Rules:

`https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/api-reference.html#retention-rules`